# Bookshelf.js relation for loosely related data

Tags: bookshelf.js, knex.js

I have a hotel table, and an amenity table. The only way they are "related" is via location, using PostGIS for PostgreSQL. In SQL I use a query like this to find the 5 nearest amenities to a hotel:

`SELECT amenity.name, amenity.brand, ST_Distance_Sphere(hotel.geom, amenity.geom)
FROM amenity, hotel
WHERE slug='city-plaza'
ORDER BY ST_Distance(hotel.geom, amenity.geom)
LIMIT 5;`

Is there a way I could add a "nearestAmenities" field to the Hotel model using Bookshelf, which would be a collection of Amenity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I found to this was to use SQL views in addition to Bookshelf's `belongsToMany` feature. Here are the steps using the above table names, in case anyone else stumbles upon this question:

1) Add a view 'hotel_amenity':

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW hotel_amenity AS
SELECT h.id         hotel_id,
       a.id         amenity_id,
       ceil(ST_Distance(ST_Transform(h.geom, 3414), ST_Transform(a.geom, 3414))/100)/10 distance_km
  FROM amenity a
  CROSS JOIN hotel h;
```

2) Add a Amenity model with Bookshelf:

```
var Amenity = exports.Amenity = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'amenity'
});
```

3) Add a Hotel model with Bookshelf, and reference Amenity using `belongsToMany`:

```
var Hotel = exports.Hotel = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'hotel',
  nearbyAmenities: function() {
    return this.belongsToMany(Amenity, 'hotel_amenity')
    .withPivot('distance_km')
    .query('orderBy', 'distance_km', 'asc')
    .query('limit', 10);
  }
});
```

And don't forget to use `withRelated` when you fetch Hotel.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the [knex.raw](http://knexjs.org/#Raw) functionality?

```
knex.raw('SELECT amenity.name, amenity.brand, ... LIMIT 5').then(function(resp) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Hi @Matt, thanks for the suggestion. Falling back to knex is definitely a great option for anyone using Bookshelf. I have been doing my best to massage table structures and models into the Bookshelf world though so will answer my own question below on how I did it.